# Troubles with arrays in c

Tags: c

So I am currently getting into programming and I'm trying to write this code, but I am having trouble with arrays. I have read a lot of articles online and it seems that this code should work, but for some reason there is an error when I pass my arrays between my functions. Ignore the commented out section in the middle that is where I got it to work inside my main function. For this assignment I need it to work in the functions I defined below. I am just wanting to initialize my array in one function then print it out in the other. 
Thanks!

here is the error it displays
prelab7.c:32: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘print_array’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
prelab7.c:7: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int’

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int errorcheck(int );
void intializearrary(int[], int);
void print_array(int [], int);

int main()
{
    int maxsize,i;
    int n[maxsize];

    printf("\nEnter the size of the input: ");
    scanf("%d", &maxsize);

    while (errorcheck (maxsize))
    {
        printf("\nInvalid input enter the size of the input again");
        scanf("%d", &maxsize);
    }

/*  srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < maxsize; i++)
    {
    n[i] =  generaterandomnumber();
    printf("\nn[%d]=%d", i, n[i]);
    }
*/

    print_array( n[i], maxsize);

return 0;
}

int errorcheck (int maxsize)
{
    if (maxsize < 0 || maxsize > 100)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

void initializearrary( int n[],int maxsize )
    {
        int i;

        srand(time(NULL));

        for (i = 0; i < maxsize; i++)
        {
            n[i] = rand()%10;
        }
    }

void print_array(int n[], int maxsize)
{
    int i; //counter
    printf("\nInput Array\n");
    for (i = 0; i < maxsize; i++)
    {
{
   printf("\t%d", n[i]);
    }
}

/*int generaterandomnumber()
{
    return rand()%10;
}*/
```

Comment: And where is the code?

Comment: We can't help you unless you tell us the error and give the part of your code causing it.

Comment: To my mind, the problem's on line 14

Comment: I know this is so stupid -.- First i tried uploading a picture of my code that i screenshoted and it wouldn't let me do that cause I don't have enough points. Then I copied and pasted it from my terminal and it won't let me post it because of formatting issues. My code is formatted correctly. So I'm at a loss.

Comment: When you do post the code, also post the exact error you get. "There is an error" is not very specific.

Comment: Alright I'm trying to figure other ways to post it. I'll post the error too.

Comment: You have to indent code with 4 spaces.

Comment: You just need to use `print_array(n, maxsize);`.  `n[i]` means to get the value stored `i` elements away from the start of `n`.  And if you're going to use `int n[maxsize];`, you should probably move it after the loop since you don't actually have a value for `maxsize` yet.  ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move

```
int n[maxsize];
```

Just after the `while` loop and change

```
print_array( n[i], maxsize);
```

To

```
print_array( n, maxsize);
```

The former is done so that `maxsize` gets initialized before the VLA is constructed.
The latter is done because `print_array` expects an `int*` as the first argument, but you pass an invalid argument `n[i]` which is of type `int`.

Comment: However when I run the program it doesn't generate random numbers, but instead the same numbers every time. Is there something wrong I did when storing my random numbers generated in my array?

Comment: Use srand(time(NULL)) **once** at the start of main.